# As we are all trying to learn, should abbreviations be fully explained when used?

Tags: discussion

As we are all trying to learn, should abbreviations be fully explained when used?

Nothing worse than not understanding all these new abbreviations.

Answer (score 3):

Always try to write for *clarity.*

**The lifeblood of this site is *search,*** so your writing should reflect your best efforts to communicate concepts and share knowledge for the large, diverse audience looking for this content. It's common for a community to embrace their own lingo and to start abbreviating the concepts and products they use every day, but try to avoid obfuscating those important keywords for which most folks are searching.

You don't have to get carried away with it. Sometimes an abbreviation becomes so ubiquitous, it virtually *replaces* the original phrase it represents (think SDK, API, International Business Machines).

While you can assume an avid community will *generally* understand the concepts being discussed here, many people have different backgrounds and areas of study, so the folks who come here looking for help aren't always going to be up on your latest buzzwords, abbreviations, and jargon for every product released yesterday. So err towards clarity; it will make this site a more useful and discoverable resource to those seeking your help.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the abbreviations wouldn't be Stellar specific. In my opinion you shouldn't take the burden of teaching Crypto to new arrivals.

There are a few sites that try to do that already and do a reasonable job of it.
I only remember Decryptionary, Cryptocurrency Dictionary, and it seems to be down.

I think we should find one, have it in the back pocket for whenever people ask and help to actively maintain it.